# Store a matrix function for a particular value of its argument and use it without calling the function again?

Tags: functions, matrix

Suppose I have defined a function as:

```
f[x_]:={{x,x^2},{x^3,x}};
g[x_]:=f[x][[1,2]]+f[x][[2,2]]+f[x][[2,1]]
```

Now if I want to calculate `g[x]` at some value of `x`, then each term of the rhs will call `f[x]` separately which will intern slow down the process. Is there any way so that if I set the `x` value for that value each term of `g[x]` will not calculate `f[x]` separately? Therefore if it calculate `f[x]` at the given `x` value once, the each term of the rhs will be calculated from there.

Comment: Simplest is `g[x_] := With[{e=f[x]}, e[[1,2]]+e[[2,2]]+e[[2,1]]]`. You could also use multipart `Extract`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It solved my problem.